# Segregating MVC list into multiple divs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am a newbie. Just a follow-up question to a previous question: ["How to Display a list of objects in MVC View?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346376/how-to-displaying-a-list-of-objects-in-mvc-view). My question is: how do I divide this list into multiple lists, each list with 5 objects and segregate each list to a different div?

List Controller:
I am filtering out rows from a db with this controller:

```
public ActionResult FilteredElements()
    {
        var elem = DB.elements.Where(a => a.Criterion == "criterion")
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.ElementFrequency.Count())
            .ToList();

        return View(elem);
    }
```

The current view I have will enlist all the elements at once:

```
@foreach (var elem in Model)
{
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Table", new{ id = elem.ElementID }, "")">
<img src="@elem.ImagePath" /></a>
}
```

Instead of listing all the elements at once in one div, I would like to list first 5 elements in first div, next 5 in 2nd div and so on.

Comment: Please provide some code with this. Right now, you're way too broad. Just because this question relates to a previous one of yours doesn't exempt you from having to put relevant code into this question.

Comment: Why do you want to "divide" the list ? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker: the style for every 5 elements would be different from each other. So segregating into different divs would be essential I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate through that list and make use of linq functions `.Skip` and `.Take`.

**Notes:** Using `.Skip(listIndex * listSize)` you make sure that you don't display again values from past. And `.Take(listSize);` is used to take the amount elements you want to display.

```
@{
    var listSize = 5;
    var numberOfLists = Model.Count/listSize;
    for (int listIndex = 0; listIndex < numberOfLists; listIndex++)
    {
        var list = Model.Skip(listIndex * listSize).Take(listSize);

        <div id="list@listIndex">
            <p>List @listIndex </p>
            @foreach(var element in list)
            {
                 <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Table", new{ id = element.ElementID }, "")">
                 <img src="@element.ImagePath" /></a>
            }
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Why am I getting the error:  'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model>' does not contain a definition for 'Skip'. I have "using System.Linq;" in my model. framework is mvc3.

Comment: You are using `@using System.Linq;` at the top of the View?

Answer (score 0):

okay, so if you want to break your list in sets of say 5 you can use for loop and index instead of foreach for iterating over that list as

```
@for (int i=0;i<=Model.Count; i+=5)
{
    <div class="group">
    for(int j=0;(j<5)&&(i+j-1)<Model.Count;j++)
    {
        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Table", new{ id = Model[i+j].ElementID }, "")">
        <img src="@Model[i+j].ImagePath" /></a>
    }
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind dropping the `div` requirement you could get cleaner Razor this way...

```
@{ int i = 0; }
@foreach (var elem in Model)
{
    if (i++ % 5 == 0)
    {
        <h3>List @(i / 5 + 1)</h3>
    }
    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Table", new{ id = elem.ElementID }, "")">
    <img src="@elem.ImagePath" /></a>
}
```

Otherwise this also seems to work okay...

```
@{ int i = 0; }
@foreach(var elem in Model)
{
    if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        @:<div><p>List @(i / 5 + 1)</p>
    }
    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Table", new{ id = elem.ElementID }, "")">
    <img src="@elem.ImagePath" /></a>
    if (++i % 5 == 0)
    {
        @:</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: The second example works great if you change the i++ to ++i so that the increment happens before the modulus.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer which loops with value (**v**) and index (**i**) of model item in foreach

**View**

```
<div class="group"> // open and closing div tags for structure and default requirement

  // add 1 to index to make correct comparison with .Count() and %
  @foreach (var elem in Model.Select((v, i) => new { i = i + 1, v }))
  {
    // display stuff
    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Table", new{ id = elem.v.ElementID }, "")">
        <img src="@elem.v.ImageUrl" />
    </a>

     // Check if item is multiple of 5 and not the last one in the loop
     if(elem.i % 5 == 0 && elem.i != Model.Count()) { 

       // close and open div . Top and bottom div tags keeps structure
       @:</div><div class="group"> 

    }
   }

</div>
```